# Add a JButton to a JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I have a `JTable` with a model created like this :

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {},new String[] {"Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6", "Col7", "Col8"}) {
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
switch (column) {
case 0: return ImageIcon.class;
case 7: return JButton.class;
default: return String.class;
}
}
};
table = new JTable(model);
```

But when I use the `addRow` method, My `ImageIcon` appears properly but not the `JButton`. In fact, I get something like `javax.Swing.JButt...` instead of the `JButton`!

Answer (score 2):

When you are adding a new row, it is being populated correctly. (You can see the `ImageIcon`).
So, the `JButton` object is also being inserted correctly.

The only difference here, `JTable` does not know how to display it or handle events on it.

That is why `JTable` calls `toString()` method on `JButton` and displays the text (as you mentioned).

> javax.swing.JButt......

---

To overcome this problem, we need to supply two additional objects to the `JTable`.

1. [**`TableCellEditor`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html) to handle events.
2. [**`TableCellRenderer`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) to handle painting.

---

You can find additional information about implementation details here : [How to use custom JTable cell editor and cell renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858286/how-to-use-custom-jtable-cell-editor-and-cell-renderer)

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

---

**Edit in response to the comment.**

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
// Put painting logic in MyCellRenderer class.
```

This way you can assign different renderer objects to different columns.

Comment: OK, I understand the problem now. But I want to know how to make the JTable know that in a specific column I want JButton objets?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `JTable` doesn’t support a button renderer or editor. You can overcome it using a custom cell editor, [ButtonColumn](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) : http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/