# How can I add custom JComponent in a single JTable cell?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell, netbeans-8

I want to make a JTable , where **one single cell** (not all rows of a column) will contain a **JComponent** like **JdatePicker** or **JComboBox**.
I have written this code

```
    DefaultTableModel dm;
    dm = new DefaultTableModel() {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return !(columnIndex == 0); //make 0th column non-editable
        }
    };
    Object [] columnHeaders=new Object[]{"Field", "Value"};
    Object [][] data=new Object[][]{{"ID",""},{"Reg Year",""},{"Reg Date", ""}} ;

    regFormTable.setModel(dm); //regFormTable is a Jtable object
```

I also have a class that implements TableCellrenderer:

```
public class datePickerCellRenderer extends JFrame implements TableCellRenderer{
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    this.add(new JDateChooser());
    return this;
}

}
```

How can I use *datePickerCellRenderer* class to implement as I described. I tried a few ways. None of those worked. 
[Using Netbeans GUI builder is there a way to do that?]

**Plaese ask if any more code I need to add**

Comment: You'll need a renderer _and_ an editor; only return a custom component when the row & column parameters match your chosen row & column; please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach..

Comment: You could take a look at this Stack Overflow question and answers: [How to use custom JTable cell editor and cell renderer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858286/how-to-use-custom-jtable-cell-editor-and-cell-renderer).

Comment: most of JDatePickers/Calendars has own code for TableCellEditor/Rendere