# JCheckBox inside JTableCell appear and disappear on click

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a table in which a column needs to be a 'checkbox-column". And I wrote the code like this.

```
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test0 {
    
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Test0 test = new Test0();
                test.launch();
            }
            
        });
    }
    
    private void launch() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Object[][] data = {{Boolean.TRUE}};
        String[] columnName = {"Checkbox here!"};
        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data,columnName) {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex){
                return Boolean.class;
            }
        });
        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("HI");
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(checkBox));
        JScrollPane tableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.add(tableScrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When I run this, the checkbox with a "HI" label was not there as I want to be.
Instead, a normal checkbox appeared and when I clicked that, my checkbox appeared and disappeared quickly.
I don't understand what caused that. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: You need to implement the [renderer as well as the editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858286/ddg#11858569)